# io.Copy vs gsutil - copying large files to GS

Tags: go, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

After a lot of tests, we cannot seem to match the speed of gsutil when using the GS Go client libraries.
Even a skeleton file with simplest `io.Copy()` take **A LOT** longer the the simplest gsutil.

```
ctx := context.Background()
client, err := storage.NewClient(ctx, option.WithCredentialsFile(*flags.credsFile))
bucket := client.Bucket("my_bucket")
File, _ := os.Open("path_to_file")
wc := bucket.Object("remoteFile").NewWriter(ctx)
_, _ = io.Copy(wc, File)
err = wc.Close()
```

Also tried with `io.CopyBuffer()` when buffer is 128x1024, better, but still slow.

Any way to speed up the upload while using go? we dont want to call any external utilities...

Comment: Are we talking about uploading file as per your example ot moving files around what @mark is suggesting? Also if you could at least run the same command using gsutin and go program but simply prefix it with time we would know what you are reffering to.

Comment: There are two areas where `gsutil` is smarter than a simple `io.Copy`. The first is bucket to bucket object copy. @Mike Schwarts provides a good answer. The second is parallel uploads. `gsutil` can break up a single file into multiple segments and upload those in parallel. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploads-downloads#parallel-composite-uploads

Comment: did you manage to find any way to copy large files efficiently using the stand go `storage` library?

Comment: @Avishay28 I ended up using gsutil - its magical :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the io.Copy implementation is not GCS aware, and instead is doing actual byte copies (reading from the source file and writing to the destination file). In contrast, gsutil is calling the GCS [Rewrite](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/rewrite) API, which for the cases where the source and destination are in the same location and storage class, will do metadata-only copies (avoiding byte copying). Doing it that way is far faster, which would match what you're observing, performance-wise.

Can you use a GCS aware Go implementation -- i.e., one that will call Rewrite rather than reading/writing the underlying object bytes?

Comment: What do you mean by "calling the Rewrite", there is some library? from the documentation I can't understand how to use it when I want to copy a local file (which I guess is the use-case of the OP)- You need to provide `sourceBucket` `sourceObject` in the request URL

Comment: Avishay28 - I haven't worked with the Go library but looking at the documentation it looks like you want to use the CopierFrom function: https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/storage#ObjectHandle.CopierFrom